# Why I am getting this error while working with react based on my code?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, frontend

Error:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

where my code is getting infinite loops?

I am trying to validate the form using react, reactstrap.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Col, Row, FormFeedback } from "reactstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Contact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      telnum: "",
      email: "",
      agree: false,
      contactType: "Tel.",
      message: "",
      touched: {
        firstname: false,
        lastname: false,
        telnum: false,
        email: false,
      },
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur(this);
  }

  //hanldeBlur function is declared

  handleBlur = (field) => (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      touched: { ...this.state.touched, [field]: true },
    });
  };

  validate(firstname, lastname, telnum, email) {
    const errors = {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      telnum: "",
      email: "",
    };

    if (this.state.touched.firstname && firstname.length < 3) errors.firstname = "First Name should be >= 3 characters";
    else if (this.state.touched.firstname && firstname.length > 3) errors.firstname = "First Name should be <= 10 characters";

    if (this.state.touched.lastname && lastname.length < 3) errors.lastname = "Last Name should be >= 3 characters";
    else if (this.state.touched.lastname && lastname.length > 3) errors.lastname = "Last Name should be <= 10 characters";

    const reg = /^\d+$/;
    if (this.state.touched.telnum && !reg.test(telnum)) errors.telnum = "Tel. Number shoould contains only numbers";

    if (this.state.touched.email && email.split("").filter((x) => x === "@").length !== 1) errors.email = "Email should contain @";

    return errors;
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
    alert("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    const errors = this.validate(this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname, this.state.telnum, this.state.email);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <Breadcrumb>
              <BreadcrumbItem>
                <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
              </BreadcrumbItem>
              <BreadcrumbItem active>Contact Us</BreadcrumbItem>
            </Breadcrumb>
            <div className="col-12">
              <h3>Contact Us</h3>
              <hr />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row row-content">
            <div className="col-12">
              <h3>Location Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4 offset-sm-1">
              <h5>Our Address</h5>
              <address>
                121, Clear Water Bay Road
                <br />
                Clear Water Bay, Kowloon
                <br />
                HONG KONG
                <br />
                <i className="fa fa-phone"></i>: +852 1234 5678
                <br />
                <i className="fa fa-fax"></i>: +852 8765 4321
                <br />
                <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
              </address>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-6 offset-sm-1">
              <h5>Map of our Location</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-11 offset-sm-1">
              <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                <a role="button" className="btn btn-primary" href="tel:+85212345678">
                  <i className="fa fa-phone"></i> Call
                </a>
                <a role="button" className="btn btn-info">
                  <i className="fa fa-skype"></i> Skype
                </a>
                <a role="button" className="btn btn-success" href="mailto:confusion@food.net">
                  <i className="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <h3>Send us Your Feedback</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-9">
              <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>
                    First Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={10}>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="firstname"
                      name="firstname"
                      placeholder="First Name"
                      value={this.state.firstname}
                      valid={errors.firstname === ""}
                      invalid={errors.firstname !== ""}
                      onBlur={this.handleBlur("firstname")} //hanldeBlur function is called
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <FormFeedback>{errors.firstname}</FormFeedback>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label htmlFor="lastname" md={2}>
                    Last Name
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={10}>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="lastname"
                      name="lastname"
                      placeholder="Last Name"
                      value={this.state.lastname}
                      valid={errors.lastname === ""}
                      invalid={errors.lastname !== ""}
                      onBlur={this.handleBlur("lastname")} //hanldeBlur function is called
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <FormFeedback>{errors.lastname}</FormFeedback>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label htmlFor="telnum" md={2}>
                    Contact Tel.
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={10}>
                    <Input
                      type="tel"
                      id="telnum"
                      name="telnum"
                      placeholder="Tel. Number"
                      value={this.state.telnum}
                      valid={errors.telnum === ""}
                      invalid={errors.telnum !== ""}
                      onBlur={this.handleBlur("telnum")} //hanldeBlur function is called
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <FormFeedback>{errors.telnum}</FormFeedback>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label htmlFor="email" md={2}>
                    Email
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={10}>
                    <Input
                      type="email"
                      id="email"
                      name="email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      valid={errors.email === ""}
                      invalid={errors.email !== ""}
                      onBlur={this.handleBlur("email")} //hanldeBlur function is called
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                    <FormFeedback>{errors.email}</FormFeedback>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Col md={{ size: 6, offset: 2 }}>
                    <FormGroup check>
                      <Label check>
                        <Input type="checkbox" name="agree" checked={this.state.agree} onChange={this.handleInputChange}></Input>{" "}
                        <strong>May We Contact You?</strong>
                      </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={{ size: 3, offset: 1 }}>
                    <Input type="select" name="contactType" value={this.state.contactType} onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                      <option>Tel.</option>
                      <option>Email</option>
                    </Input>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label htmlFor="message" md={2}>
                    Your Feedback
                  </Label>
                  <Col md={10}>
                    <Input type="textarea" id="message" name="message" rows="12" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleInputChange}></Input>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Col md={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                    <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                      Send Feedback
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: When in the component lifecycle does the error occur? What reproducible steps do you have?

Comment: Maybe `this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur(this);` should be `this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);`

Comment: thank you @lastr2d2  for noticing that error. it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have reworked some of the code and created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-chatterjee-u5jbt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark), where the issue does not exist.

Most noticeable change would be the `handleBlur` function. You should always use a functional state update to access the old state.

```js
  handleBlur = (field) => (evt) => {
    this.setState(({ touched }) => ({
      touched: { ...touched, [field]: true },
    }));
  };
```